How do I create a quarto filter which can update the description of a post listing?
From my tests (and from code), it appears that the message of a listing post cannot be updated on runtime (when quarto is rendering the HTML).
A want a lua filter that overrides this functionality and instead generates a custom description will be used by the listing page.

Could you clarify, please: what exactly should the filter do, what kind of "update" do you want to see for the description, and do you have any code but got stuck? A reproducible example would be extremely helpful, too.

I cannot follow. Could some client-side (JS) code solve your problem?
